# Python throws ModuleNotFoundError only on one computer

Tags: python, python-3.x, module

I have a Python project structure like this:

```
 └── my_project
     ├── __init__.py (empty)
     ├── options.py
     └── main.py
```

inside `main.py` I import `options` like so:

```py
from my_project.options import some_function
```

However (and this is the weird part - this only happens on one computer (Python 3.9.1)) when running `main.py` I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../my_project/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from my_project.options import some_function
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_project'
```

This  used to work before, but has now for some reason broken. Do you have any idea as to why it might not wanna work, and how I can fix it? It also works just fine when I install this program with `pip` - just not when ran locally with my Python interpreter

Answer (score 0):

Check for the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable, which is the default path to search for `python` modules.

Must contain the root path of your project. You can find more info [here](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#environment-variables)

Comment: That seems fine, and exactly the same as in my other machine, so there's something else wrong